# VBA does not catch SAP list's row

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am working on SAP GUI Scripting with VBA. I have 200 lines of information to enter into SAP from Excel. However, SAP list hits 23 lines max, which you have to than scroll down to enter more lines into the list. Here is my code

```
i = 0
With session
    .findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "MIGO"
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/txtGOHEAD-BKTXT").Text = "PKG QTY REF 015835"
    While Cells(7 + i, 1).Value <> ""
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-MAKTX[1," & i & "]").Text = Cells(7 + i, 2)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/txtGOITEM-ERFMG[4," & i & "]").Text = Cells(7 + i, 4)
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-ERFME[5," & i & "]").Text = "PC"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-LGOBE[6," & i & "]").Text = "BORD"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-NAME1[12," & i & "]").Text = "2S98"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMLGOBE[27," & i & "]").Text = "DMDV"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32," & i & "]").Text = "CATNEW"
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32," & i & "]").SetFocus
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/ctxtGOITEM-UMBAR[32," & i & "]").caretPosition = 6
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM").verticalScrollbar.Position = i
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End With
```

I tried using

```
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM").verticalScrollbar.Position = i
```

to scroll down the list but apparently VBA still stops at line 23. Is there another for all my 200 lines to be added inside the list?

[image]

Here is a picture of how it looks like when my code ran, There are lines below 23 but VBA still stops and doesn't continue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have you tried manually entering data above 23 lines? Are these lines are disabled after 23rd row?
Below should do the job. I usually scroll and set my last row on top. BTW Which t-code are you using?

```
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0006/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM").verticalScrollbar.Position = i
```

Comment: im using t-code :Migo and no, the lines are not disabled.